# proper use of googleVis in R Presenter

Tags: r, googlevis

I'm trying to embed `googleVis` motion chart in R Presenter presentation but am not able to get the chart to display inside presentation, although this code does work in R command line.

````
```{r, echo=FALSE}
library(googleVis)
data(Fruits)
M <- gvisMotionChart(Fruits, idvar="Fruit", timevar="Year")
plot(M)

```
````

Nothing shows up on the page inside R Presenter slide.

Comment: I've used an iframe myself with decent success.

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem. No solution from me. Just thought I'd share the heavy heart.